# MVC4 application - configure as a web application under root site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 application. When I deploy as a website in IIS 7, it works. but when I deploy it under root website as an application it fails to map route and gives http 404 on second get/post.

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
localhost/Home/Login

Ideally it should go on url - **localhost/MVCApp/Home/Login**

Comment: When you select your site, and then click "Browse" in Actions pane at the right hand side of the screen, are you able to see you site? if not what error message it gives?

Comment: When i browse first time - it goes to localhost/MVCApp4/Home/Login. But then I click on any action it tries to go without app name ie. localhost/Home/action..